# Is there a way to colorize the git add --interactive mode?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I am using `git add --patch` a lot and I am looking for a way to have its output colorize (like in `git diff --color`).

Is there something out there or should I try and write a wrapper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `.gitconfig`:

```
[color]
    interactive = true
```

I'm not sure *exactly* how this will get colorized, but that's the builtin option.

Comment: Worked great. I also added `diff = true` for the rest of it.

Comment: @vrinek if you want everything colorized, you can just add `ui = true` to that section, IIRC. I recommend you look at the "Variables" section of [the git-config man page](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), there's tons of cool stuff you might not have known about

Comment: `ui = true` looks like an even better solution. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could run it through Perl or somesuch and inject [colour codes](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/terminal_colours/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with adding 'ui = true' to the config file is that it impacts other commands.  For example, if you use 'git diff file.c > patch" to save patch files, the escape codes that make the color might end up in the output file.

Other options are to do it the command line:

```
git -c color.ui=true add -p foo.c
```

or, make an alias in the .git/config file:

```
[alias]
  addp  = -c color.ui=true add -p
  addi  = -c color.ui=true add -i
```

Comment: That is why you use `git diff | patch`, not `git diff > patch`. If so it won't include any color escape codes.

Comment: `git config --global color.ui auto`

Answer (score 0):

Before Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), the reimplemented "[`git add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/644591bd0659979f46f92baab197af633f30931d/Documentation/git-add.txt#L89)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--i))</sup> did not honor `color.ui` configuration.

See [commit 6f74648](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f74648cea1ada4dd0add46b2ae038606bb47395) (07 Jun 2023), and [commit 7cf3b49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cf3b49f47f02ed1cab5b1cd03a5e27acaa13c99) (06 Jun 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 644591b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644591bd0659979f46f92baab197af633f30931d), 22 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cf3b49f47f02ed1cab5b1cd03a5e27acaa13c99): check `color.ui` for interactive add
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Greg Alexander</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When '[`git add -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7cf3b49f47f02ed1cab5b1cd03a5e27acaa13c99/Documentation/git-add.txt#L89)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--i))</sup> and '[`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7cf3b49f47f02ed1cab5b1cd03a5e27acaa13c99/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> were converted to a builtin, they introduced a color bug: the '`color.ui`' config setting is ignored.
>
> The included test demonstrates an example that is similar to the previous test, which focuses on customizing colors.
> Here, we are demonstrating that colors are not being used at all by comparing the raw output and the color-decoded version of that output.
>
> The fix is simple, to use `git_color_default_config()` as the fallback for `git_add_config()`.
> A more robust change would instead encapsulate the `git_use_color_default` global in methods that would check the config setting if it has not been initialized yet.
> Some ideas are being discussed [on this front](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.1539.git.1685716420.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/), but nothing has been finalized.
>
> This test case naturally bisects down to [0527ccb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0527ccb1b558e1337f5f3e02ea9747d86a1908a8) ("`add -i`: default to the built-in implementation", 2021-11-30, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fc1879839242dbb1a378888b68493cbb04b07e0) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bcf4f6271ad8c952739164d160e97efd579424f)), but the fix makes it clear that this would be broken even if we added the config to use the builtin earlier than this.